# Lotus scripts Set value(Unique Number) in each document from GetAllDocumentsByKey

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

From my code below try to Looping from "GetAllDocumentbyKey" and Set Unique number each document for to show in Folder View , but from my code it's not work. 
How should I solve this problem?

```
Dim defect As Variant
defect = uidoc.FieldGetText("DefectMode")
keys( 0 ) =defect
Dim PartNo As Variant
partNo = uidoc.FieldGetText("PartNo")
keys( 1 ) = partNo

Set view = db.GetView("EmbedView2" )

Set dc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(keys,False)
Call dc.PutAllInFolder("EmbedFolder")

Do Until dc Is Nothing
    call uidoc.FieldSetText("UniqueNo","number") // this code I try to set unique number to each document by number that's I plan to increase 1 , I have to set in "UniqueNo" Fieled
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK... There is a big part missing from your code.

uidoc is the currently open document and if I guess right, it has an embedded view in it called "EmbedFolder". The documents you want to modify all belong to a special DefectMode and a special PartNo (that of the currently open document)

I doubt that what you want makes sense, but I don't wanna go into that.

To make your code work you need to cycle through the document collection and set each documents value separately. This would simply look like this:

```
Dim intNumber as Integer
Dim doc as NotesDocument
intNumber = 1
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()
Do until doc is Nothing
  Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "UniqueNo" , intNumber )
  Call doc.Save( True, True, True )
  Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Code in above it's work well.

Comment: Arita: I strongly recommend that you find yourself a good tutorial on LotusScript and the Lotus classes. Here's one, but there are others: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27010431

Comment: Richard Schwartz: Thank you for your advice .